# Societal impact of research

Tags: research-process

As someone who conducts research that is unlikely to be of any relevance to the common man, I would like a little perspective on the impact that pure research plays in society, and how I can, in some sense, feel *better* about my research contributions.

In a field such as pure mathematics, one can argue that most people are unlikely to understand, or even be interested in recent results. In my opinion, pure mathematicians are attracted to the unhindered joy of research and the challenges it brings, and this is a major factor in the field being active today. (For the record, I am not a pure mathematician.)

In contrast, research in fields such as medicine and environmental science seem to have a larger impact on the common man. A simple example would be the Covid-19 vaccines that will play a major role in bringing the world back to a semblance of normality. Even if it can be argued that today's mathematical results will shape the science and engineering of tomorrow, I continue to feel that these will not have as large an impact as medical research will continue to.

My question is simple: Though I am someone who conducts research motivated simply by the challenges it brings and the joy of achieving a solution, I do occasionally feel that I would like my research to have a larger impact on society (which it really does not). I would like to know if there are others that feel the same way, particularly from a field such as mathematics, and if so, how I can obtain a new perspective on this.

Comment: Something you'll no doubt hear is that research has been deemed of value by higher authorities than the common person, the good of all, that sort of thing. So whatever you're doing to advance knowledge is a societal asset whether society knows it or not. I suspect you are wrestling with that justification. Good luck to you, it's a worthwhile question.

Comment: Thank you, that is indeed what I am wrestling with.

Comment: And spend some time exploring how diverse the “common man or woman” is. Pluralism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to think longer term. Decades, and perhaps centuries. Research done today may seem to have little immediate impact, and that is true. But over time, it contributes to the general knowledge that makes things possible. Think of any scientist from the past whose name is known today, even, say, Euclid. Some of what they did may have had some immediate effect, but much of it laid the groundwork for later advances.

In pure mathematics and theoretical physics, for example, an interesting question today may be vital in the future. Isaac Newton's calculus work was so unimportant that he put it in a drawer for years. Leibniz did "interesting" things in understanding real functions, but without their work, and what came after, much of engineering in the past 150 or so years would be impossible.

Think Mendel or Darwin. They studied and thought because certain questions were "interesting" to them. They laid the foundation of modern understanding and that led to "useful" things.

Note that Einstein's work took years to be accepted because the "great minds" of the day were focused on a different theory that turned out to have no basis - the aether.

Moreover, many of the advances of the "great minds" of science were only possible because of a general advancement in understanding, much of which was contributed by those whose names we no longer remember. The current state of understanding the world can be thought of as an advancing front with many contributors, some of whose contributions we remember specifically, but it is the front itself that makes them possible. All of us push against that frontier in our small, perhaps, ways.

Comment: I think if you've been blessed with the opportunity to do research, whether someone is paying you specifically for it or not, pursue it. @Buffy makes a very good point on the potential for your research to come into its own far after you've moved on. We see the same thing in the arts. Your insights don't need to be practical or immediately of interest to others, particularly if you're doing research for the pleasure of it as Darwin, Newton, etc., probably did.

Comment: I’m almost certain cryptography was a field of mathematics that was pushed aside as unimportant for quite some time. That is, until WW2. Now, we are seeing cryptography come back with a vengeance in the cryptocurrency space. Who knows what impact your research will have, that’s part of the fun.

Comment: Thanks, this answer is quite helpful...

Comment: @GrayLiterature Cryptographers cringe when people compare that field with cryptocurrency. Cryptocurrency is a very small application of cryptography and is only tangentially related. Cryptography came back with a vengeance in the 90s, long before Bitcoin.

Answer (score 3):

I think Buffy's answer hits an important point to reconsider your time horizon in evaluating the social impact of research.

I'm writing here to suggest how it is the cumulative sum and multiplicative effect of the entire body of researchers working towards expanding knowledge that has a profound effect, even if a single researcher makes a minimal individual impact.  In other words, to suggest individual research is not worth the effort is similar to suggesting that voting is not worth the effort.  Sure, one missing vote does not matter too much, but if no one voted?  It's the same with acts of kindness, littering, eating right, etc.

In sum, we research because of the virtue of the act of pursuing research.  We are the truth seekers. We gradually illuminate the darkness, even if it is little by little.  "If I have seen further it is by standing on the shoulders of Giants", as it were. (and things like combustion engines, penicillin, plastic, indoor plumbing, etc. are nice bonuses, too).

Comment: Gauss: An interesting connection to your namesake. I understand he felt his research in pure mathematics, say number theory and the theory of equations, wasn't the thing he was being supported for, yet he pursued it, I suppose, as a calling.

Answer (score 1):

I want to put a new perspective on it. As scientists we are in some term the modern 'magicians'. We take matter and transform it into all kinds of different forms and shapes.

Whereas the mathematicians find new principles in the world of numbers and of geometry the theoretical physicist binds these findings to the physical world.

Of course, the laws found herein can be used by chemists and material scientists to create new kinds of materials (but taken into account your elaborated question, you know all of this already).

The important point I want to make here is that I don't think it is important *what* we actually do in science. It is more important *how* we do it and how we can learn to use our mind. Because in the end, we cannot say if the things we invent or discover will actually serve humanity or not. For this, the world is far too complex.

This is why I think in academia it is much more important that students learn how to think as much as they learn that thinking is not everything.

Science is just embedded into the society and in humanity as a whole. And hoping to contribute to the advancement of humanity by doing inventions might be a dead end.

Once this is realized we can see that our main purpose in academia is to raise students that can shape their world and their future in a meaningful way.